# Click on dynamically loaded content iterates event

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click, iteration

I load dynamical content like this:

```
$('.cPopUpOverlay').fadeIn('fast');
$('.cPopUpOverlay').append('<div class=\'cPopUpContent\'></div>');
$('.cPopUpContent').load('popups/popup_1.php');
$('.cPopUpContent').fadeIn('fast');
```

The popup_1.php has some data + a simple button.

```
<input type='button' id='btn_action_add' action='add' value='add'>
```

Again, from the page where I executed the first 4 lines of code there is this:

```
$('.cPopUpOverlay').on('click', 'input[type=\'button\']', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $('.cPopUpOverlay').fadeOut();
    $('.cPopUpOverlay').html('');
}
```

Basically, it sends "clicked" to the console and removes the content of popup_1.php and closes it.

This all works well. Except ... When I open the popup, console displays "clicked", when I re-open the popup, it displays "clicked (3)". Again after close and click it displays "clicked (6)"

Every time i re-open the popup, it executes the click n-times where n is the number of times i open the popup. It's like the click event remains somewhere and is executed again and again as if with each opening of the pop-up there's an extra button that is evaluated when the .on('click') event fires.

I don't understand why this is. I clear the content by using:

```
$('.cPopUpOverlay').fadeOut();
$('.cPopUpOverlay').html('');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the whole code? it seems you're redeclaring the listener on each click

Comment: That was it. So obvious. Pretty embarassed over here ...

Answer (score 0):

As Amenadiel suggested ... I redeclared the listener on each click. So obvious I missed it. Sorry :-/